# NIO Hang Up Problems?

Tags: java, networking, nio, java-7, java.nio.file

I'm having problems with sending data over SocketChannels between a Host and Client using the NIO framework.

I've never really bothered to learn NIO before now, but with the introduction of the java.nio.files package and other various improvements I thought I would give it a try.

I'm able to get the SocketChannel and ServerSocketChannel to connect fine, but the actual data transfer is acting very weird.  It NEVER finishes correctly on the Client side, always hanging up after the final read.  Furthermore, it sometimes reads the incorrect amount of data (too much or too little) and has even caused Windows Explorer to go crazy and allocate literally ALL of the system's memory, crashing the computer.

Here is the code (it is test code) I have right now:

```
package bg.jdk7.io;

import static java.nio.file.StandardOpenOption.*;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.net.InetSocketAddress;
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
import java.nio.channels.FileChannel;
import java.nio.channels.ServerSocketChannel;
import java.nio.channels.SocketChannel;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.nio.file.StandardOpenOption;

public class NetIO {

static volatile long filesize;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    new Thread(new Client()).start();
    try {
        ServerSocketChannel ssc = ServerSocketChannel.open();
        ssc.bind(new InetSocketAddress(5555));
        SocketChannel sc = ssc.accept();
        if(sc.isConnected()) {
            ByteBuffer buff = ByteBuffer.allocate(10240);
            Path fp = Paths.get(System.getProperty("user.home")+"\\Documents\\clip0025.avi");
            if(Files.exists(fp)) {
                FileChannel fc = (FileChannel) Files.newByteChannel(fp, StandardOpenOption.READ);
                long tot = Files.size(fp);
                long run = 0;
                int read = 0;
                int prog = 0;
                while((read = fc.read(buff))>0) {
                    buff.rewind();
                    sc.write(buff);
                    run+=buff.position();
                    int last = prog;
                    prog = (int)(((double)run/tot)*100);
                    if(prog !=last) {
                        System.out.println(prog + "%");
                    }
                    buff.flip();
                }
                fc.close();
                System.out.println("Sending completed");
            }
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

---

```
static class Client implements Runnable {

    public void run() {
        try {
            SocketChannel sc = SocketChannel.open();
            sc.connect(new InetSocketAddress("localhost",5555));
            if(sc.isConnected()) {
                Path dpf = Paths.get("\\NIO_TESTING\\");
                Path dp = Paths.get(dpf+"\\clip.avi");
                Files.createDirectories(dpf);
                FileChannel fc = (FileChannel)  Files.newByteChannel(dp, CREATE, WRITE, TRUNCATE_EXISTING);
                ByteBuffer buff = ByteBuffer.allocate(10240);
                int read;
                int total = 0;
                while((read = sc.read(buff))>0) {
                    total+=read;
                    buff.rewind();
                    fc.write(buff);
                    System.out.println(fc.size());
                    buff.flip();
                    if(total == filesize) System.out.println("File data received successfully...");
                }
                System.out.println("Completed successfully");
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A `SocketChannel` resulting from `ServerSocketChannel.accept()` *is* connected. There is no way it can't be. The `isConnected()` test is pointless.

Your server I/O code is incorrect. Channel writes must be preceded by `buffer.flip()` and followed by `buffer.compact().` The canonical way to copy from one channel to another is as follows (note that this behaves correctly at EOS even when there is pending data still in the buffer):

```
while (in.read(buffer) >= 0 || buffer.position() > 0)
{
  buffer.flip();
  out.write(buffer);
  buffer.compact();
}
```

Similarly to my first paragraph, a `SocketChannel` resulting from `SocketChannel.open()` followed by `SocketChannel.connect()` *is* connected: again, the test is pointless. If it wasn't connected there would have been a `ConnectException` on the `connect()` call.

Your client I/O code has the same problems as your server I/O code.

You aren't closing the `SocketChannel` in the server, so the client will never stop reading from the connection.

You aren't closing the `SocketChannel` in the client either.

The `File.exists()` test is pointless. The following line will throw an exception if the file isn't there, and you have to handle that exception anyway, so why do it all again?

Comment: Er... yes I'm new to NIO, as well as the JDK 7 API.  Thanks for your help though.  I will try these changes.  What about buffer.rewind()?  Does that need to be used?

Comment: And wouldn't closing the SocketChannel close the underlying Socket?

Comment: @ghostsoldier23 This isn't the JDK 7 API. Most of it is the JDK *1.4* API. Of course closing the channel closes the socket, as it says in the Javadoc, but you aren't doing that. The only thing you are closing is the FileChannel, and that only in the server. So you are missing three closes. You don't need `buffer.rewind()`, just what I posted.

Comment: It worked.  Thanks for your help.  And I can't help but recognize you... you also corrected my traditional I/O library code a while back :D